# My balance variable wont update/show in my JLabel

Tags: java, netbeans

Im using netbeans to create a simple clicker game. you click the button to get money.
at the top of the screen I have a jlable set to display the balance of the player

```
balDisplay = new javax.swing.JLabel();
balDisplay.setText("Balance: ¢"+bal);
```

although when I run it all it displays is "Balance: ¢0"
Ive set it up so for the button click event not only does it add money to the player balance but it prints the balance amount in the console, and every time you click you get the specified money like I set it up to. Its just that the label wont display it.
this is what im doing for the mouse click event

```
private void clickMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    bal = bal+100;
    System.out.println(bal);
}
```

Comment: You've got "magical" thinking going on. Just because you've changed the value of bal, it's not going to "magically" change the display in the JLabel. **You've** got to do this programmatically by calling `setText(...)` on the JLabel when the value of bal changes.

Comment: Side recommendation: don't add MouseLIsteners to JButtons. For many reasons, you should use ActionListeners instead. And again, *within* the listener call `setText(...)` on that JLabel for reasons I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

the `setText()` evaluates  immediately and does not bind to the value of `bal`

ie

```
a = 1;
b = a;
a = 2;
```

for the same reason that `b` is not updated to 2, the label's text will not be recomputed.

The fastest way yo fix this is to add `balDisplay.setText("Balance: ¢"+bal);` where ever you change `bal`. a more robust solution would be to fire an even when `bal` is updated and have the label subscribe to the event.